# Inserting user input to an array in a loop and then printing it, C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

How do I send values from userinput to an array in a loop that will be saved in the array in memory and the how do I print all values in that array. (C#)

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter name of ingredient " + (i + 1) + ":");
Console.WriteLine("Enter quantity of " + ingredient + " :");                         
Console.WriteLine("Enter unit of measurment for " + ingredient + " :");
```

This is the values i would need to save in the loop and after every loop it would have to save another value as ingredient. For example the first ingredient saved to the array would be an apple and the second could be a banana and they both need `your text`to be saved to the array and then displayed.

Comment: An [example](https://www.w3resource.com/csharp-exercises/array/csharp-array-exercise-1.php) you might want to go through.

Comment: I guess you first find out how to read values from the console. then you learn how to use loops and arrays.  you will find countless resources and tutorials on these topics. split your problems into atomic steps. programming is about abstracting problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following may help you get started - [using Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0) instead of arrays might be a better approach.  You can copy and paste the code below into: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ and then run it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        
        List<String> ingredient_names_list;
        List<String> ingredient_units_list;
        List<int> ingredient_quantity_list;
        
        String ingredient_name;
        String unit_measure;
        
        int i;
        int ingredient_num;
        int quantity;
        
        
        // Initialize lists ...
        
        ingredient_names_list = new List<String>();
        ingredient_units_list = new List<String>();
        ingredient_quantity_list = new List<int>();
        
        
        // Loop to get ingredients ...
        
        ingredient_num = 0;
        
        Console.WriteLine( "Enter name of ingredient " + ( ingredient_num + 1 ) + ":" );
        ingredient_name = Console.ReadLine();
        
        while ( !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( ingredient_name ) )
        {
        
            ingredient_names_list.Add( ingredient_name );
            
            Console.WriteLine( "Enter quantity of " + ingredient_name + ": " );  
            quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            ingredient_quantity_list.Add( quantity );
            
            Console.WriteLine( "Enter unit of measurement for " + ingredient_name + ": " );
            unit_measure = Console.ReadLine();
            ingredient_units_list.Add( unit_measure );
            
            ingredient_num++;
            
            Console.WriteLine( "Enter name of " + ( ingredient_num + 1 ) + ":" );
            ingredient_name = Console.ReadLine();
            
        }
        
        // Display all ingredients ...
        
        for ( i = 0; i < ingredient_names_list.Count; i++ )
        {
        
            ingredient_name = ingredient_names_list[ i ];
            quantity = ingredient_quantity_list[ i ];
            unit_measure = ingredient_units_list[ i ];
            
            Console.WriteLine( "Ingredient " + ( i + 1 ) );
            Console.WriteLine( "- Name: " + ingredient_name );
            Console.WriteLine( "- Quantity: " + quantity );
            Console.WriteLine( "- Unit measure: " + unit_measure );
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help i have looked at this method of doing it but my assignment says specifically to use arrays

Comment: @Avient_711 - I have posted another answer using arrays - hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Below is another version using parallel arrays - hope that helps.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        
        const int k_ingredients_count_max = 10;
        
        String[] ingredient_names_array;
        String[] ingredient_units_array;
        int[] ingredient_quantity_array;
        
        String ingredient_name;
        String unit_measure;
        
        int i;
        int ingredient_count;
        int quantity;
        
        
        // Initialize arrays ...
        
        ingredient_names_array = new String[ k_ingredients_count_max ];
        ingredient_units_array = new String[ k_ingredients_count_max ];
        ingredient_quantity_array = new int[ k_ingredients_count_max ];
        
        
        // Loop to get ingredients ...
        
        ingredient_count = 0;
        
        Console.WriteLine( "Enter name of ingredient " + ( ingredient_count + 1 ) + ":" );
        ingredient_name = Console.ReadLine();
        
        while ( !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( ingredient_name ) && ingredient_count < k_ingredients_count_max )
        {
        
            ingredient_names_array[ ingredient_count ] = ingredient_name ;
            
            Console.WriteLine( "Enter quantity of " + ingredient_name + ": " );  
            quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            ingredient_quantity_array[ ingredient_count ] = quantity;
            
            Console.WriteLine( "Enter unit of measurement for " + ingredient_name + ": " );
            unit_measure = Console.ReadLine();
            ingredient_units_array[ ingredient_count ] = unit_measure;
            
            ingredient_count++;
            
            Console.WriteLine( "Enter name of " + ( ingredient_count + 1 ) + ":" );
            ingredient_name = Console.ReadLine();
            
        }
        
        // Display all ingredients ...
        
        for ( i = 0; i < ingredient_count; i++ )
        {
        
            ingredient_name = ingredient_names_array[ i ];
            quantity = ingredient_quantity_array[ i ];
            unit_measure = ingredient_units_array[ i ];
            
            Console.WriteLine( "Ingredient " + ( i + 1 ) );
            Console.WriteLine( "- Name: " + ingredient_name );
            Console.WriteLine( "- Quantity: " + quantity );
            Console.WriteLine( "- Unit measure: " + unit_measure );
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
}
```